# Can't Serialize DataTable which is part of a DataSet

Tags: .net

I've got a DataSet with some DataTables in it. I can binary serialize the DataSet successfully.

If I try to serialize one of the DataTables separately I get a NullReferenceException.

If I make a copy of the DataTable then the copy serializes fine.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

This code reproduces the issue:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.String xml =
            "<CR><AN>543</AN><Br>XYZ</Br><Id>888</Id><M>123456</M><EVT>DATA</EVT><data><telephony><S>2012-01-11T14:01:54.9571247Z</S><CID>100000</CID><reason>test</reason></telephony></data></CR>";

        var ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        using (var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml))
        {
            ds.ReadXml(stringReader);
        }

        //This works.
        var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(memStream, ds);
        }

        System.Data.DataTable dt0 = ds.Tables[0];

        //Serializing a copy works
        System.Data.DataTable copy = dt0.Copy();
        using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(memStream, copy);
        }

        //Serializing the original fails with a NULL Reference Exception
        using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(memStream, dt0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the problem is serializing a DataTable that has a relation to another DataTable and serializing the whole DataSet at once. Maybe we should just call it a bug. Another way to solve this is to call `dt0.ChildRelations.Clear()`, but then you could just call `Copy()` instead. Note that if you copy a `DataTable` all relations are getting removed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO it's a bug. I will call serializing dataset as case A, datatable as case B and copied datatable case C

Your deserialized dataset has two tables `CR` and `data` with a relation between them. In case B, internals lose some info about `data` table (collection `rowsOrder` to be more precise).

Sequence of fail:

1. internal class `NewDiffgramGen` maintains rows order of:

   - all tables in dataset (case A)
   - one provided table (case B)
   - one provided table (case C)
2. internal class `XmlDataTreeWriter` serializes DataRows recursively through child relations, these are cleared during coping in case C
3. in case B `XmlDataTreeWriter` fails on `this.rowsOrder[row].ToString()` and throws `NullReferenceException`

So you have three options:

- serialize whole dataset
- clear `dt0.ChildRelations`
- serialize a copy

Comment: Arrrh smashing, I see it's the ChildRelations, that's brilliant, thanks; in my case I can just remove these. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

`dt0.Copy()` doesn't copy exactly the same object as `dt0`. I debugged your code and the `copy` object doesn't contains a `DataSet` instance. So, if you need to serialize the `DataTable` object, probably serialize the copy is the best option.

Comment: Why downvote? dt0 is attached to its dataset while dt0.Copy() is not. Maybe serializing a datatable with attached dataset is not allowed and this is the reason for the exception. (that is how i understood @Agustin Meriles answer).